# Data argument not used by format string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, nsstring

I'm trying to let the user post a status on facebook and I get the error: "Data argument not used by format string" on this code:

> [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This
>   is quite average.",mySLComposerSheet.serviceType]];

Anyone see what is wrong?

Best regards,
Øyvind Larsen Runestad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, by using stringWithFormat, it's expecting you to use % which is a specifier for format. If your string is simply, "This is quite average." then do the following line.

```
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"This is quite average."]
```

If you're trying to append "This is quite average." to mySLComposerSheet.serviceType, then do the following

```
NSString* text = [mySLComposerSheet.serviceType stringByAppendingString:@"This is quite average."];
```

and then do

```
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:text];
```